# How to connect two or more database tables to find a keyword with search bar

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two or more databases in MySQL. I want to create a search bar where I can find a keyword from any database's tables. This code is for a single database with three tables -- `messages`, `topics`, `comments`.

---

```
$query = "(SELECT content, title, 'msg' as type FROM messages WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'topic' as type FROM topics WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'comment' as type FROM comments WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%')";

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: What you have here is enough to bring your server to it's knees (never mind the possibility of sql injection) do this on another DB as well and you would need a fire extinguisher

Comment: create instances of database and use those in query with respective tables and after getting the result from all queries collaborate the result from array which you get.

Comment: a) **don't** use `mysql` functions - they are deprecated and in PHP7 removed. use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. b) use **parameterized queries** for better performance and to protect yourself against **SQL injection**. c) you should read up on fulltext searches

Answer (score 0):

can you trying below code

```
$query = "(SELECT content, title, 'msg' as type FROM DBA.messages WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'topic' as type FROM DBA.topics WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'comment' as type FROM DBA.comments WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%')
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'msg' as type FROM DBB.messages WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'topic' as type FROM DBB.topics WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'comment' as type FROM DBB.comments WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%')
           ";

mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: when i found keywords from multiple tables then on clicking on a particular keyword from suggestions by search bar..how would i know which database and table belongs to that keyword.

Comment: how to display its database and table name..plz assist me